# How to have multiple tasks under one role in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am setting up Ansible as a newbie. I would like to group a few tasks under an Nginx role.

See my folder structure

[image]

The only way I could get this to work is to use include statements in my playbooks... but that means I needed to start changing everything to relative paths since Ansible stopped being able to find things.

My playbook currently:

```
- name: 
    Install Nginx, Node, and Verdeccia
  hosts: 
    all
  remote_user: 
    root
  tasks:
    - include: ../roles/nginx/tasks/install.yml
    - include: ../roles/nginx/tasks/create_node_config.yml
  vars:
    hostname: daz.com
```

How can I reference the `sub task` in the playbook to be something like

```
tasks:
  - nginx.install
```

and still be within best practices.

Comment: I'd suggest you to stop there and read the documentation about roles, as the way your are doing it right now is absolutely not how you should use them. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of roles so far is not in line with the norm or the idea of Ansible. From a purely technical point of view, it is quite possible that you have multiple task bundles in yml files that you include in the playbook.

If you want to include a specific task file from a role, you should better do this via the [module `include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) with the parameter [`tasks_from`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from).

However, the workflow with roles usually looks different.

1. in the folder `tasks` should always be a file `main.yml`, this is called automatically, if simply the role is included, no matter over which way.
2. in this `main.yml` you can then add further control logic to include your `yml` files as required.

As it looks to me, for example, you always need to install, but depending on the use case you want to have different configurations.

1. create in your `nginx` role a file `defaults/main.yml`.

   ```yaml
   ---
   config_flavor: none
   ```

   This initializes the `config_flavor` variable with the string `none`.
2. create in your `nginx` role a file `tasks/main.yml`.

   ```yaml
   ---
   - name: include installation process
     include_tasks: install.yml

   - name: configure node
     include_tasks: create_node_config.yml
     when: config_flavor == "node"

   - name: configure symfony
     include_tasks: create_symfony_config.yml
     when: config_flavor == "symfony"

   - name: configure wordpress
     include_tasks: create_wordpress_config.yml
     when: config_flavor == "wordpress"
   ```

   - The `main.yml` will be included by default when the role is applied.
   - This is where the installation is done first, then the proper configuration is done.
   - Which configuration should be done is defined by the variable `config_flavor`. In the listed example the values are `node`, `symfony` and `wordpress`. In all other cases the installation will be done, but no configuration (so in the default case with `none`).
3. include your role in the playbook as follows

   ```yaml
   ---
   - name: Install Nginx, Node, and Verdeccia
     hosts: all
     remote_user: root

     vars:
       hostname: daz.com

     roles:
       - role: nginx
         config_flavor: node
   ```

   At this point you can set the value for `config_flavor`. If you set `wordpress` instead, the tasks `create_wordpress_config.yml` will be included automatically, using the logic from `tasks/main.yml`.

You can find [more about **roles**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) in the Ansible Docs.

There are many more possibilities and ways, you will get to know them in the course of your learning. Basically I would recommend you to read a lot in the Ansible docs and to use them as a reference book.

Comment: Mate thankyou very much for taking the time to explain this. I am so new to it but I have a big job to do. Your solution helps me out a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to bellow document. you can use "include_role" with "tasks_from" attribute. you don't need to provide full path of task files, Just file names.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html

Example:

```
- name: Run tasks/other.yaml instead of 'main'
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: myrole
    tasks_from: other
```